# Instantiating a 2d array in a java constructor?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, 2d

I am so confused. I need to make a constructor to create a 2d array with parameters called from main method.. Every time I call the Seats 2D array in another method of the same class, I get an error. Why is that and how do I use the array I made in the constructor?

```
class MovieSeating 
{

public MovieSeating(int rowNum, int columnNum)
{
    String [][] Seats = new String[rowNum][columnNum];
    for (int r = 0; r < rowNum; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < columnNum; c++)
        {
            Seats[r][c] = "???";
        }
    }
}

private Customer getCustomerAt(int row, int col)
{
    System.out.println("Customer at row " + row + " and col " + col + "." );
    System.out.println(Seats[row][col]);

}
```

Comment: `I get an error`, what is the error?

Comment: I added the next method so you can see what I am doing.

Answer (score 3):

You are on a good track, but you have to make `Seats` instance variable in order to get proper results:

```
private String [][] Seats;
public MovieSeating(int rowNum, int columnNum)
{
    Seats = new String[rowNum][columnNum];
    for (int r = 0; r < rowNum; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < columnNum; c++)
        {
            Seats[r][c] = "???";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the array outside the constructor as a private variable :

```
class MovieSeating 
{
    private String [][] Seats;
public MovieSeating(int rowNum, int columnNum)
{
    Seats = new String[rowNum][columnNum];
    for (int r = 0; r < rowNum; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < columnNum; c++)
        {
            Seats[r][c] = "???";
        }
    }
}

private void getCustomerAt(int row, int col)
{
    System.out.println("Customer at row " + row + " and col " + col + "." );
    System.out.println(Seats[row][col]);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MovieSeating{

private String[][] seats;

public MovieSeating(int col, int row){
  seats = new String[row][col];
}
}
```

Make seats an *instance variable* to increase the scope of it.

Answer (score 0):

`Seats` is not known in the `main`, it's known only in the scope of the constructor.

You should make it a [*class member*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) and initialize it in the constructor:

```
class MovieSeating  {
   private String [][] Seats;
   ..
   public MovieSeating(int rowNum, int columnNum) {
      Seats = new String[rowNum][columnNum];
      ..
   }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how to fix that.

Comment: @user2875661 See the tutorial I linked you to, and see my update.

Answer (score 0):

Here i am sending code snipped i hope this will help u

```html
public Charts(int graph_min, int graph_max, double[] dataset, int stepSize,double[][] percentRange) {

//here double[][]={{10},{100}};
  this(graph_min,graph_max,dataset);
  this.stepSize = stepSize;
  
  System.out.println("double constructor    "+percentRange.length);
  this.percentRange = new double[percentRange.length][percentRange[0].length];
  System.out.println("percentRange: "+this.percentRange);
   for (int i = 0; i < percentRange.length; i++) {
   
         for (int j = 0; j < percentRange[i].length; j++) {
              this.percentRange[i][j] = percentRange[i][j];
               System.out.println("ps_Axis constructor valuesd  "+this.percentRange[i][j]);
            }
        
 }
```